# Collapsable Drawers breaking

Tags: javascript, html, css

Got another question today. I am trying to now work out how to implement collapsible drawers. As shown on this: http://codepen.io/nodws/pen/lahqf I only want to use the creators’ transparent one.

I cut out most of the unnecessary code and it worked fine on its own, but when I placed it into my website it stops working. I am wondering if something else is causing it to break.

My attempt is here:
http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/QGbWKK

CSS

```
/* =Reset default browser CSS. Based on work by Eric Meyer: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

del {
  text-decoration: line-through; }

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

a img {
  border: none; }

/* =Scss Variables
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* =Global
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  background-color: #3cb5f9;
  color: #505050;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.8; }

/* Headings */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 300; }

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3cb5f9; }

a:hover {
  color: #0793e2; }

/* =Template
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; }

#main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 150px; }

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px; }

.containertwo {
  width: 86%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px; }
.containertwo h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  padding: 60px 0; }
  section h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 10px; }
  section p {
    margin-bottom: 30px; }
    section p:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0; }
  section.color {
    background-color: #d51c84;
    color: white; }

/* =Info Bar
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#info-bar {
  background-color: #000000; }
  #info-bar a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px; }
    #info-bar a:hover {
      background-color: #0793e2; }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials,
  #info-bar span.back-to-tutorial {
    display: block;
    width: 50%; }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials {
    float: left;
    text-align: left; }
  #info-bar span.back-to-tutorial {
    float: right;
    text-align: right; }

/* =Header
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#logo img {height: 40%;}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
  -o-transition: height 0.3s;
  transition: height 0.3s; }
  header h1#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s; }
  header nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right; }
    header nav a {
      line-height: 150px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 18px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s; }
      header nav a:hover {
        color: white; }
  header.smaller {
    height: 75px; }
    header.smaller h1#logo {
      width: 150px;
      height: 75px;
      line-height: 75px;
      font-size: 30px; }
    header.smaller nav a {
      line-height: 75px; }

/* =Footer
-------------------------------------------------------------- */


*, *:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #242424;
  padding: 20; margin: 30;
}

html, body{background: rgb(0, 0, 0);}

.content{
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 350px; /* Same height as footer */
}

.fixed_footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background: #000000;
  position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  padding:100px 5px;
}
   .fixed_footer p{
    color: #696969;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 50px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
}
/* =Extras
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  height: 0; }

/* =Media Queries
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
  /* =Header
  -------------------------------------------------------------- */
  header h1#logo {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center; }
  header nav {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto; }
    header nav a {
      line-height: 50px;
      margin: 0 10px; }
  header.smaller {
    height: 75px; }
    header.smaller h1#logo {
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
      font-size: 30px; }
    header.smaller nav {
      height: 35px; }
      header.smaller nav a {
        line-height: 35px; } }
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%; }

  #info-bar a {
    display: block; }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials,
  #info-bar span.back-to-tutorial {
    width: 100%; }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials,
  #info-bar span.back-to-tutorial {
    float: none;
    text-align: center; }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #0793e2; } }

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  /* &:nth-of-type(1) */
}
section h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
section:nth-of-type(1) {
  /* .paralax-1 */
}
section:nth-of-type(1) .paralax-1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* .new-paralax */
}
section:nth-of-type(1) .paralax-1 .new-paralax {
  z-index: -100000;
  transform: translateZ(-8000px) scale(0.4);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.3);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url("https://visualhunt.com/photos/xl/2/aerial-view-of-coffee-cup-on-wooden-table.jpg");
}
section:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 20em;
  background-image: url("http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/iStock_000068237701_Full-edited.jpg");
}
section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: white;
}
section:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-image: url("https://visualhunt.com/photos/xl/2/sport-gymnastics-frog-funny-fitness-fit-sporty-1.jpg");
}
section:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-color: white;
}
.collapse {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:0px;
  max-height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.collapse * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
.collapse.active {
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 200;
  color:#444;
  max-height:3000px;
  padding:10px 20px;
  margin: 10px -10px;
  transition: all 0.2s,max-height 4.8s;
}
.collapse h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position:relative
}
.transparent{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0) !important;
  color:#fff !important;
  box-shadow:none !important;
  margin:0px !important;
  padding:10px !important
}
.collapse h2::after{
  content: "+";
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:50%;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:15px;
  opacity:0.5;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
.collapse:hover h2::after{
  opacity:1
}

.collapse.active h2::after{
  content: "-";
}
```

JS

```
/*!
 * classie v1.0.0
 * class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * MIT license
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true, unused: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );

$('.collapse').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

HTML

```
<!-- title and meta -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<title>Header Resize On Scroll with Animations</title>

<!-- css -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<!-- js -->
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script>
    function init() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                shrinkOn = 300,
                header = document.querySelector("header");
            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                classie.add(header,"smaller");
            } else {
                if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                    classie.remove(header,"smaller");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = init();
</script>
</head>



<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<header>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1 id="logo">
            <img src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/bilendi-logo-trans.png">
        </h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="">Lorem</a>
            <a href="">Ipsum</a>
            <a href="">Dolor</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header><!-- /header -->
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content">
    <main class="content" role="main">

        <section>
            <div class="container">
              <h2>Services for Market Research</h2><br> 
              <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll. Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
                <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</p>
              <div class="collapse transparent">
    <h2>I am transparent</h2>
    The brain is like a muscle. When it is in use we feel very good. Understanding is joyous.
    <b>Carl Sagan</b> 
    <p>This one keeps the transparency</p>
  </div>
                <p>
                    <a href="http://www.bilendi.co.uk">&laquo; Want to know more?</a><br>
                    <a href="http://www.bilendi.co.uk">&laquo; Become a citizen!</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="color">
            <div class="container">
              <h1>Cupcakes for the people!</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="color">
            <div class="container">
                <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll. Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
                <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Sugar rush, oh my...</h1>
                <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll. Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
                <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
      <section>
            <div class="containertwo">
              <h3>Enquire</h2>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://bilendi.formstack.com/forms/js.php/bilendi_test_2"></script><noscript><a href="https://bilendi.formstack.com/forms/bilendi_test_2" title="Online Form">Online Form - BILENDI TEST 2</a></noscript><div style="text-align:right; font-size:x-small;"><a href="http://www.formstack.com?utm_source=jsembed&utm_medium=product&utm_campaign=product+branding&fa=h,2521222" title="HTML Form Builder">HTML Form Builder</a></div>
        </div>
              </section>
    </main></div>
</div><!-- #main -->


<footer class="fixed_footer">
  <div class=" container content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis ducimus nemo quo totam neque quis soluta nisi obcaecati aliquam saepe dicta adipisci blanditiis quaerat earum laboriosam accusamus nesciunt! Saepe ex maxime enim asperiores nisi. Obcaecati nostrum nobis laudantium aliquam commodi veniam magni similique ullam quis pariatur voluptatem harum id error.</p>
  </div>
</footer>



</div><!-- /#wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow by pasting my code directly into the codepen for the collapsable drawers pen. It made it suddenly work....yet I see no differences between the two bits of code.... God knows how I got this working.

Here is the new working one:
http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/MbwLBa

CSS

```
/* =Reset default browser CSS. Based on work by Eric Meyer: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

del {
  text-decoration: line-through; }

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

a img {
  border: none; }

/* =Scss Variables
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* =Global
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  background-color: #3cb5f9;
  color: #505050;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.8; }

/* Headings */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 300; }

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3cb5f9; }

a:hover {
  color: #0793e2; }

/* =Template
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; }

#main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 150px; }

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px; }

.containertwo {
  width: 86%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px; }
.containertwo h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  padding: 60px 0; }
  section h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 10px; }
  section p {
    margin-bottom: 30px; }
    section p:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0; }
  section.color {
    background-color: #d51c84;
    color: white; }

/* =Info Bar
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#info-bar {
  background-color: #000000; }
  #info-bar a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px; }
    #info-bar a:hover {
      background-color: #0793e2; }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials,
  #info-bar span.back-to-tutorial {
    display: block;
    width: 50%; }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials {
    float: left;
    text-align: left; }
  #info-bar span.back-to-tutorial {
    float: right;
    text-align: right; }

/* =Header
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#logo img {height: 40%;}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
  -o-transition: height 0.3s;
  transition: height 0.3s; }
  header h1#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s; }
  header nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right; }
    header nav a {
      line-height: 150px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 18px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s; }
      header nav a:hover {
        color: white; }
  header.smaller {
    height: 75px; }
    header.smaller h1#logo {
      width: 150px;
      height: 75px;
      line-height: 75px;
      font-size: 30px; }
    header.smaller nav a {
      line-height: 75px; }

/* =Footer
-------------------------------------------------------------- */


*, *:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #242424;
  padding: 20; margin: 30;
}

html, body{background: rgb(0, 0, 0);}

.content{
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 350px; /* Same height as footer */
}

.fixed_footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background: #000000;
  position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  padding:100px 5px;
}
   .fixed_footer p{
    color: #696969;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 50px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
}
/* =Extras
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  height: 0; }

/* =Media Queries
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
  /* =Header
  -------------------------------------------------------------- */
  header h1#logo {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center; }
  header nav {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto; }
    header nav a {
      line-height: 50px;
      margin: 0 10px; }
  header.smaller {
    height: 75px; }
    header.smaller h1#logo {
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
      font-size: 30px; }
    header.smaller nav {
      height: 35px; }
      header.smaller nav a {
        line-height: 35px; } }
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%; }

  #info-bar a {
    display: block; }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials,
  #info-bar span.back-to-tutorial {
    width: 100%; }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials,
  #info-bar span.back-to-tutorial {
    float: none;
    text-align: center; }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #0793e2; } }

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  /* &:nth-of-type(1) */
}
section h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
section:nth-of-type(1) {
  /* .paralax-1 */
}
section:nth-of-type(1) .paralax-1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* .new-paralax */
}
section:nth-of-type(1) .paralax-1 .new-paralax {
  z-index: -100000;
  transform: translateZ(-8000px) scale(0.4);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.3);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url("https://visualhunt.com/photos/xl/2/aerial-view-of-coffee-cup-on-wooden-table.jpg");
}
section:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 20em;
  background-image: url("http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/iStock_000068237701_Full-edited.jpg");
}
section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: white;
}
section:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-image: url("https://visualhunt.com/photos/xl/2/sport-gymnastics-frog-funny-fitness-fit-sporty-1.jpg");
}
section:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-color: white;
}
.collapse {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:0px;
  max-height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.collapse * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
.collapse.active {
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 200;
  color:#444;
  max-height:3000px;
  padding:10px 20px;
  margin: 10px -10px;
  transition: all 0.2s,max-height 4.8s;
}
.collapse h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position:relative
}
.transparent{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0) !important;
  color:#fff !important;
  box-shadow:none !important;
  margin:0px !important;
  padding:10px !important
}
.collapse h2::after{
  content: "+";
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:50%;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:15px;
  opacity:0.5;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
.collapse:hover h2::after{
  opacity:1
}

.collapse.active h2::after{
  content: "-";
}
```

JS

```
/*!
 * classie v1.0.0
 * class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * MIT license
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true, unused: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );

$('.collapse').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

HTML

```
<!-- a merger of three different codepens by three different authors.
http://codepen.io/madshaakansson/
http://codepen.io/Nickies/pen/ZYwJZM
the third one I can't remember right now but will credit when I find it
-->

<!-- title and meta -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<title>Header Resize On Scroll with Animations</title>

<!-- css -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<!-- js -->
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script>
    function init() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                shrinkOn = 300,
                header = document.querySelector("header");
            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                classie.add(header,"smaller");
            } else {
                if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                    classie.remove(header,"smaller");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = init();
</script>
</head>



<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<header>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1 id="logo">
            <img src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/bilendi-logo-trans.png">
        </h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="">Lorem</a>
            <a href="">Ipsum</a>
            <a href="">Dolor</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header><!-- /header -->
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content">
    <main class="content" role="main">

        <section>
            <div class="container">
              <h2>Services for Market Research</h2><br> 
              <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll. Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
                <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</p>
              <div class="collapse transparent">
    <h2>I am transparent</h2>
    The brain is like a muscle. When it is in use we feel very good. Understanding is joyous.
    <b>Carl Sagan</b> 
    <p>This one keeps the transparency</p>
              </div>
                <p>
                    <a href="http://www.bilendi.co.uk">&laquo; Want to know more?</a><br>
                    <a href="http://www.bilendi.co.uk">&laquo; Become a citizen!</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="color">
            <div class="container">
              <h1>Cupcakes for the people!</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="color">
            <div class="container">
                <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll. Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
                <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Sugar rush, oh my...</h1>
                <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll. Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
                <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream macaroon applicake.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
      <section>
            <div class="containertwo">
              <h3>Enquire</h2>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://bilendi.formstack.com/forms/js.php/bilendi_test_2"></script><noscript><a href="https://bilendi.formstack.com/forms/bilendi_test_2" title="Online Form">Online Form - BILENDI TEST 2</a></noscript><div style="text-align:right; font-size:x-small;"><a href="http://www.formstack.com?utm_source=jsembed&utm_medium=product&utm_campaign=product+branding&fa=h,2521222" title="HTML Form Builder">HTML Form Builder</a></div>
        </div>
              </section>
    </main></div>
</div><!-- #main -->


<footer class="fixed_footer">
  <div class=" container content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis ducimus nemo quo totam neque quis soluta nisi obcaecati aliquam saepe dicta adipisci blanditiis quaerat earum laboriosam accusamus nesciunt! Saepe ex maxime enim asperiores nisi. Obcaecati nostrum nobis laudantium aliquam commodi veniam magni similique ullam quis pariatur voluptatem harum id error.</p>
  </div>
</footer>



</div><!-- /#wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you pulling in jQuery? The handler in the example you linked to requires the use of jQuery.

This bit:

```
$('.collapse').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

So make sure you are pulling it in if you want to use that Pen.

Comment: Ah....I did not realise it was jQuery.... that explains it.... This will sound like a silly question but how do I pull in jQuery?

Comment: Download from here: http://jquery.com/
You will want to pull it in at the bottom of your page, before the closing body tag. You should not need to do much more than just pulling in the library in order to make your function work for you.

To pull it in, add:   <script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-your-jquery-document-goes-here.js"></script>

Comment: Thank you that is really helpful!